# attoparsec: succeeding on part of the input instead of failing

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I have an `attoparsec` parser, and tests for it, what annoys me is that if I comment part of the parser and run the tests, the parser doesn't return `Left "parse error at line ..."` but instead I get `Right []`.

Note that I'm using `parseOnly` to make it clear that there'll be no more input.

Otherwise it's nice to get the partially parsed input, it can definitely be useful and I'm glad to have it. However I'd like to be informed that the whole input was not consumed. Maybe to get a character offset of the last consumed letter, or if that's what it  takes, at least an option to be returned `Left`.

If it's relevant, the parser can be found [there](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/projectpad/blob/master/src/Notes.hs#L43).

If I comment for instance the line:

```
            <|> PlainText <$> choice (string <$> ["[", "]", "*", "`"])
```

And run the tests, I get for instance:

```
  1) notes parsing tests parses notes properly
       simple test
       expected: Right [NormalLine [PlainText "one line* # hello world"]]
        but got: Right []
```

This is from [that test](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/projectpad/blob/master/tests/Tests.hs#L25).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on if consuming the whole input should be the property of `parseNoteDocument` or just the tests, I'd extend one or the other with [`endOfInput`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.10.1.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v:endOfInput) or `atEnd`.

I'd suggest to define a proper `Parser` for your documents, like

```
parseNoteDocument' :: Text -> Parsec NoteDocument
parseNoteDocument' = many parseLine
```

and then define `parseNoteDocument` in terms of it. Then you can use `parseNoteDocument'` in the tests by defining a helper that parses a given piece of text using

```
parseNoteDocument' <* endOfInput
```

to ensure that the whole input is consumed.

Comment: Right, with the change you suggest, instead of `Right []` I get `Left "endOfInput"`. I remember reading that with `attoparsec` you don't get the precise error reporting that you get with the older `parsec` package. For debugging purposes I guess it's possible to temporarily remove the `endOfInput` constraint and see what DOES gets through though. Won't really help me in this case though, when I hand out the parser to the end user. But I guess I can't do much. Well, thank you anyway, that's the answer!